# Angular change detection runs eight times instead four

Tags: javascript, angular

I know that if we are on development Angular runs change detection twice. In the following example, Angular runs change detection four times. Why is this happening?

```
class Category {
  constructor( private _id ) {
  }

  get id() {
    console.log('id');
    return this._id;
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  template: `
      <select class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options;" [value]="option.id">{{option.id}}</option>
      </select>
  `,
})
export class SelectComponent {
  @Input() options;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-select [options]="options"></app-select>
  `,
})
export class App {
  options = [new Category(1)]
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, SelectComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

If you run the code above you will see that the console log runs eight times instead four.

Comment: change detection runs as many times as needed for each async task in the Angular zone

Comment: Angular runs `app.tick` twice on first start

Comment: So it should console.log four times, not eight.

Comment: two for each {{options.id}} bindings.

Comment: It should log 8 times `app.tick` (detectChanges, checkNoChanges), `app.tick` (detectChanges, checkNoChanges)

Comment: `I know that if we are on development Angular runs change detection twice.` is `detectChanges` and `checkNoChanges`

Comment: So only on first init it will run detectChanges and checkNoChanges?

Comment: On first init it will run detectChanges and checkNoChanges and then detectChanges and checkNoChanges

Comment: First run https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L540 second run https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L446 `ApplicationRef.tick` executes `detectChanges` and `checkNoChanges`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: You can describe the behavior in an answer so I can choose this as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know it is not documented but angular runs additional `appRef.tick` when bootstraping application

```
 private _loadComponent(componentRef: ComponentRef<any>): void {
    this.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    this.tick();
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L540

And then it calls main handler to run change detection

```
this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe(
    {next: () => { this._zone.run(() => { this.tick(); }); }});
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L445

During the `tick` method angular runs `detectChanges` method

```
this._views.forEach((view) => view.detectChanges());
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L561

and in dev mode `changeNoChanges`

```
if (this._enforceNoNewChanges) {
    this._views.forEach((view) => view.checkNoChanges());
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L563

So angular runs change detection 4 times on first init.

Since you use getter twice in template

```
[value]="option.id">{{option.id}}
```

it will be executed twice and finally you will get 8 calls

Comment: but why it runs four times? why 1 time is not enough for cd?