# Angular 4 Change Detection Run Twice at Startup Even in Production Mode

Tags: angular

In my Angular app `ngDoCheck`, `ngAfterViewChecked` always executed twice *while startup*.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465301/in-angular2-why-are-there-2-times-check-for-content-and-view-after-settimeout?noredirect=1&lq=1) tell me that Angular calls twice the change detection after the first one, in development mode.

I have run this command to enter production mode.

```
ng serve --environment=prod --target=production
```

and, Angular still called the hook twice.

Updated:

As yurzui said in the comment, Angular run Change Detection twice in dev mode: `detectChanges` and `checkNoChanges` (*yurzui*: **i also said that [angular calls app.tick()(that includes detectChanges and checkNoChanes(dev)) method twice on first start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412199/angular-change-detection-runs-eight-times-instead-four/45412670#45412670)**). The former to propagate changes, and the latter to make sure there are no changes. (see: [Two Phases of Angular Applications](https://vsavkin.com/two-phases-of-angular-2-applications-fda2517604be))

But i don't understand why Angular calls `detectChanges` and `checkNoChanges` twice, at startup. So Change Detection called 4 times. Aren't 2 just enough?

Comment: Are you calling `detectChanges` somewhere?

Comment: My component just calling `console.log` on these hook.

Comment: are you calling `enableProdMode()` inside your `main.ts` ?

Comment: Yes, the app is generated by @angular-cli. I did not touch it.

Comment: you can check in console if angular is running in development mode or not. I think you have to use `enableProdMode()` in main.ts. Btw which version of Angular cli are you using ? update to the latest version and check. eg. beta.32-3

Comment: 1.2.1 version. I will try to install new angular-cli.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412199/angular-change-detection-runs-eight-times-instead-four/45412670#45412670

Comment: @yurzui I can't comment on your answer. `On first init it will run detectChanges and checkNoChanges and then detectChanges and checkNoChanges`, why Angular doing that, change detection 4 times? Aren't 2 times enough?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue?

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Yeah, i have updated it too)

Comment: So why 2 tick() my brother? I think 1 is enough.